# MagicalRecord access oldest element added

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, magicalrecord

I am using the amazing library MagicalRecord in my app.

I needed to make "*disk cache*" of some data in the app. To limit the size of this *cache* I wan´t to have only a maximum of 100 instances of that type of data.

One simple solution i came across was to every time a new element is added, check if the number is bigger then 100. If yes, it should remove the **oldest** **element added**.

```
ModelData *model = [ModelData MR_createEntity];
model.key = modelDataKey;
model.value = value;

[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
    NSUInteger count = [ModelData MR_countOfEntities];
    if (count > 100) {
       //remove last element added
    }
}];
```

I know i can add atribute date to my model and make a search by order, but I preferrer a better solution (if exits).

Any tips for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solution is to include a created timestamp as an attribute. I would not worry about storage or performance, this is a clean and lightweight solution.

You can add the date automatically and effortlessly by overriding `awakeFromInsert`.